# How do I remove borders or change colors and other customization in form fields on angular material 16?

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material

I recently updated my angular material version to 16 and all the UI that I had got messed up because of the introduction of mdc.

The CSS that I was changing before with

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

does not work anymore and I have been trying to find a way to do it but I have not been successful, on top of that the spacing seems to be messed up as well.

I tried this

```
::ng-deep .mdc-notched-outline {
  border: none !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

I am able to change the background color using this however, the input is not visible at all.

At this point, should I drop the angular material?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In my code base I had to do quite a lot of manual changes to make it work with the newly introduced `mdc`. I took the opportunity to gradually get rid of all my `::ng-deep` instances. I removed the styling of material components from my own components' stylesheets and instead styled them in global stylesheets that are `@use`d or `@import`ed. Thus I achieved a uniform styling of material components. It's still WIP but so far looks good. Also please avoid `important!`

Comment: Why do you wish to avoid using ng::deep, also what did you do in the CSS, can you share some insight?

Comment: Read this article: https://kevinkreuzer.medium.com/ng-deep-alternatives-b3c45c07a17. Besides, `::ng-deep` will be deprecated in the future, AFAIK

Comment: When I was looking at the mdc component, it had 3 divs inside leading and trailing that was applying borders. Am I missing something here? Cuz earlier I could remove the borders with 1 selector.

Answer (score 0):

in my project I added this in styles.scss to change grey background color to white

```
.mdc-text-field  {
 background-color: white !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

and
my in my html

```
<form [formGroup]="suggestionForm">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label >Suggestion Name:</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="text" id="name" formControlName="name" />
        </mat-form-field>
      </form>
```